# Right Outer Join Issue in a CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, common-table-expression, outer-join

Ultimately I'd like my end result to look like the following:

```
ReportingDate    FundCode    FundName    AssetClass    Rank    Percentage
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
30/11/2012       1           Fund1       Bond          1       50
30/11/2012       1           Fund1       Equity        2       30
30/11/2012       1           Fund1       Balanced      3       0
30/11/2012       1           Fund1       Other         4       20
30/11/2012       2           Fund2       Equity        1       60
30/11/2012       2           Fund2       Bond          2       20
.......
```

Basically if there is no data for say `Balanced` like in the above example I would still like this to be returned in the data but with a percentage of 0.

To get this I created a table called `@AssetClass` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` this to my work table so that I could get all the `AssetClass`'s returned even without data.

My script looks like this:

```
;;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN ReportingDate IS NULL THEN MAX(ReportingDate) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1)) 
            ELSE ReportingDate 
        END                     AS ReportingDate

    ,   CASE
            WHEN PortfolioID IS NULL THEN MAX(PortfolioID) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1)) 
            ELSE PortfolioID 
        END                     AS PortfolioID

    ,   CASE
            WHEN PortfolioNme IS NULL THEN MAX(PortfolioNme) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1)) 
            ELSE PortfolioNme 
        END                     AS PortfolioNme

    ,   AC.AssetClass           AS AssetClass

    ,   CASE
            WHEN AC.AssetClass = 'No Asset Class' THEN 3 
            WHEN AC.AssetClass = 'Other' THEN 2 
            ELSE 1
        END                     AS [Rank]
    ,   CAST(SUM(ISNULL(Percentage, 0)) AS DECIMAL(22,1))  AS [Weight]

FROM @Worktable as WT

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN @AssetClass AS AC
        ON RTRIM(WT.AssetClass) = RTRIM(AC.AssetClass)

GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, WT.PortfolioNme, AC.AssetClass
)

SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReportingDate, 103)    AS ReportingDate    
    ,   PortfolioID                             AS FundCode
    ,   PortfolioNme                            AS FundName
    ,   AssetClass
    ,   RANK() OVER (   PARTITION BY PortfolioID 
                        ORDER BY [Rank], [Weight] DESC) AS [Rank]
    ,   [Weight]                                AS Percentage
FROM CTE

ORDER BY ReportingDate, PortfolioID, [Rank], [Weight] DESC
```

My problem is, when I run this for one portfolio this works perfectly. When I run this for multiple portfolio's it seems to exclude in the final select anything where there is no data, so in the above example the `Balanced` row is not returned.

Is there an issue with my script or how I've right outer joined to `@AssetClass`? Is there something I'm missing or something I can improve upon in my script?

Comment: May you give data @Worktable table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible this can help you
UPDATE 03.01.2013

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, WT.PortfolioNme,        
       AC.AssetClass,
       CASE WHEN AC.AssetClass = 'No Asset Class' THEN 3 
            WHEN AC.AssetClass = 'Other' THEN 2 
            ELSE 1 END AS [Rank],        
       SUM(CASE WHEN AC.PortfolioID IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE WT.Percentage END)
       OVER(PARTITION BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, AC.AssetClass) AS [Weight]
FROM Worktable WT CROSS APPLY (
                               SELECT AC2.AssetClass, WT2.ReportingDate, WT2.PortfolioID,
                                      WT2.AssetClass AS AssetClass2 
                               FROM AssetClass AC2 LEFT JOIN Worktable WT2 
                                 ON RTRIM(AC2.AssetClass) = RTRIM(WT2.AssetClass)
                                   AND WT2.PortfolioID = WT.PortfolioID                                                              
                               ) AC
WHERE (WT.ReportingDate = AC.ReportingDate AND WT.PortfolioID = AC.PortfolioID AND WT.AssetClass = AC.AssetClass)
        OR (AC.AssetClass2 IS NULL)
GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, WT.PortfolioNme,          
         AC.AssetClass, AC.PortfolioID, WT.Percentage
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReportingDate, 103) AS ReportingDate,
       PortfolioID AS FundCode,
       PortfolioNme AS FundName,
       AssetClass,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID 
                    ORDER BY [Rank], [Weight] DESC) AS [Rank],
       [Weight] AS Percentage
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ReportingDate, PortfolioID, [Rank], [Weight] DESC
```

Comment: Sorry so late for me to respond.  Been off due to the Xmas and New Year.  In the '@AssetClass' table i only have the list of Asset Classes within there so the way you've suggested above will not work.  I needed to do the PARTITION BY so that it populated Reporting Date, PortfolioID and PortfolioNme with data when there was no data for an Asset Class from '@AssetClass' table.

Comment: Works perfectly mate although a little slow but at least you've given me something to work with.  Thank you very much.